# asp.net mvc mono 2.4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, vps

I am thinking of getting a $20/month VPS Ubuntu box with Slicehost.com or linode.com and running asp.net MVC on mono. Has anyone done this? I have successfully configured asp.net MVC with Apache on my local ubuntu box but I just am not sure how stable this would be? I really like the idea of root access VPS plus being able to run asp.net mvc for $20/mo would be sweet

Answer (score 2):

Jackson Harper runs his site on a similar system running on Linode.

You might want to check his blog, slides and his pre-configured appliance that runs ASP.NET MVC here:

http://blog.monoontheweb.info/

Comment: No answer for 2 days and then from the creator himself. thanks Miguel. big fan of your work.

Answer (score 2):

Miguel is right I did run that setup for quite some time.  Unfortunately that blog is down now because I am using that node for testing another project.  You might be interested in this project as it as meant to make deployment of the very setup you are talking about much easier.

More info on the project here: http://jacksonito.blogspot.com/2010/01/setting-up-mono-powered-aspnet-web.html

As per my results running my Mono web server on Linode.  I have had used that setup for two different sites and had excellent uptime and performance on both of them.  None of them were extremely popular sites but they got a couple large spikes in traffic.

Comment: You didn't happen to have Castle ActiveRecord or nHibernate running too did you?